# AutoMapper: Create a map with included classes

Tags: c#, mapping, viewmodel, automapper

I have these two view models:

```
public class SettingsViewModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public PersonalViewModel Personal { get; set; }
}

public class PersonalViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

After implementing these view models I created a map with automapper:

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<User, PersonalViewModel>()
        .ForMember(vm => vm.Birthday, m => m.MapFrom(
            u => (u.Birthday.HasValue) ? u.Birthday.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") : DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")));

    Mapper.CreateMap<User, SettingsViewModel>()
        .ForMember(vm => vm.UserId, m => m.MapFrom(
            u => u.Id));

    var viewModel = Mapper.Map<User, SettingsViewModel>(user);
```

Now I have the problem, that my property `Personal` in my `SettingsViewModel` is null. How can I combine my two mappings? How can I fill my `Personal` property with the data from my user object? In my user object, there are properties for `FirstName` und `LastName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up your mapping this way:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, SettingsViewModel>()
    .ForMember(vm => vm.UserId, m => m.MapFrom(u => u.Id))
    .ForMember(vm => vm.Personal, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u));
```

Here, we're saying *map the `Personal` property from the `User` object itself.* When you specify this, the mapping from `User` → `PersonalViewModel` will automatically be used.

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/YJnPDq